# apache httpd not found

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I installed apache2.4 on my kali linux using this commands

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/mgh-amp/apache2 --with-include-apr
$ make
$make install
```

when try to start apache , this error shown:

```
/opt/mgh-amp/apache2/bin/apachectl: 81: /opt/mgh-amp/apache2/bin/apachectl: /opt/mgh-amp/apache2/bin/httpd: not found
```